# Don't give dupe-hammer for special tags

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer, moderator-tags, required-tags

All of you know that Meta sites have special groups of tags:

- required tags: [feature-request] [support] [bug] [discussion]
- moderator tags: all of [status-*] tags

At the same time there's such feature as dupe-hammer - ability to close/reopen question with specific tag alone. This ability is given by the fact that person who has big score on the tag could be considered as an expert of something related to the tag.

But can the person be expert on [feature-request] or [status-completed]? I don't think so.

Hence, my suggestion is to exclude such special tags from the dupe-hammer ability and leave only regular tags for this purpose.

Comment: Are we solving a problem that exists? For example, [2 people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/294/status-declined) have a gold badge for [status-declined]. Has any of them ever abused the dupehammer? Why would they? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @AaronBertrand there is [a lot of people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) with required-tag dupe-hammer.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm trying to prevent closing related questions with dupe-hammer obviously.

Comment: /sigh. That's still not what I asked, as I can read the title of the question. I'm asking _why_ - why do you want to change this, what specific problems have you seen the current functionality cause (please point out any specific examples), and how will the site be better by forcing duplicates to stay open for slightly longer?

Comment: Basically you're suggesting that nobody except moderator/staff should be able to identify a bug report or a feature request as a duplicate without the help of a bunch of peers, which seems... well, silly. How many of those gold badge holders are not moderators, staff, or former staff? Of those, how many have ever abused the privilege?

Comment: As for `status-` tags - as far as I can tell, not one single question has been closed here, ever, from a gold badge in one of those tags. If you know of one, please point it out. These tags are used by moderators / staff members to indicate the outcome of a question. Why you are worried any of these will be abused, I have no idea. If you have seen abuse, please, by all means, show us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove tag badges or dupehammer on moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386146/remove-tag-badges-or-dupehammer-on-moderator-only-tags)

Comment: @nicael That question has since been duped forward into this one since this one has an answer by staff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paraphrased, the request is to:

> Prevent people with a gold badge in required and moderator-only tags from using a binding vote to close a post as a duplicate of another post.

No explanation *why* or any evidence of this having *ever* been a problem, but let's take a closer look.

#### Subjectively

Basically, you're suggesting that nobody except moderators/staff should be able to identify a question as a duplicate of another, without the help of a bunch of peers who... know better because they don't have a gold badge, but have merely earned the right to vote to close? I don't know why a person who has earned that much reputation in, say, the `feature-request` tag doesn't have enough intelligence to identify a feature request as a duplicate of another feature request, or why three people with a combined reputation potentially far less than one of the gold badge holders would absolutely know better 100% of the time. Or why we're ignoring that nearly everyone (or maybe everyone?) with a gold badge in any of these tags *is* a (former) staff member or moderator. But okay. Let's pretend it is a possibility that three average users can make a better decision than a gold badge holder about whether a feature request is, in fact, a duplicate of another feature request.

#### Objectively

Let's look at this with our good old friend, **math**.

For starters, not a single post has ever been closed on this site with a binding vote based on a gold badge in any of the `status-` tags. So let's throw those tags out the window right from the start.

Next, how many questions were asked with one of the four common required tags? Let's look at 2022 and, so far, 2023. (Some of these numbers may overlap because I ran independent queries for each tag, intentionally ignoring that they might not be mutually exclusive, and also ignored the less popular tags that are almost never used.) And let's see, for each tag, how many were closed as a duplicate, based specifically on the gold badge in that tag.

| Tag | 2022 count | 2023 count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| total questions in all tags | 3,454 | 406 |
| closed by hammer: `bug` | 104 | 11 |
| closed by hammer: `feature-request` | 52 | 7 |
| closed by hammer: `support` | 46 | 6 |
| closed by hammer: `discussion` | 246 | 14 |
| **total closed by hammer**: | 448 | 38 |
| **% closed by hammer**: | 12.97% | 9.36% |

It is quite difficult to take these *quantitative* numbers and derive any sort of *qualitative* analysis from them. Were any of these closed unjustly? Was the dupehammer abused in even one of these cases? Again, impossible to tell from the numbers, and I am more than happy to investigate any alleged *specific* cases of abuse of the dupehammer (my e-mail address is abertrand AT, you know, the famous domain here).

Barring that, I think the only thing we can really do is look at those questions using the binding vote and determine how many of them *were later re-opened*. This doesn't mean they were all absolutely closed incorrectly - sometimes it's simply because further context was added after the binding close vote occurred (especially in the case of `discussion`), sometimes it was re-opened and the tag changed because it was a support issue and not a bug or vice-versa, I recall at least one question not too long ago that was re-opened after being closed as no repro (it was just an obscure repro). There are other scenarios as well, surely, that don't smell of abuse. Anyway, here are those numbers:

| Tag | 2022: closed | later re-opened | 2023: closed | later re-opened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `support` | 104 | 2 | 11 | 0 |
| `bug` | 52 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| `feature-request` | 46 | 2 | 6 | 0 |
| `discussion` | 246 | 15 | 14 | 1 |

I'm not going to insult anyone's intelligence by even displaying the percentages there.

#### Conclusively

I think it's fair to say **this is not a problem** that requires any change in the behavior of the site.

If you have identified *real* cases of dupehammer abuse, again, I am more than happy to investigate them, and we can do it quietly / privately. Crippling very useful functionality - that seems to be used consistently a very high percentage of the time - based on, well, not sure what, is unlikely to fly.

Comment: Could you please tag this as [tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @Sonic I don't even know if I'm allowed to do that (and certainly wouldn't want to be accused of abusing that right). I'm just weighing in with data.

Comment: Staff have the ability to change moderator-only tags without a mod diamond. If it weren't allowed, why would they give out that ability? That said, feel free to consult with CMs and devs before tagging.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I know I can _technically_ change the tag, I'm saying it's not my role or right to explicitly decline a feature request. I'm also not going to escalate this to CMs on a Friday night by changing to [tag:status-review], either.